# Find limit of an integral with variable upper bounds.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac1x\int\limits_{-x}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt$$

As I understand  $\displaystyle\int_{-x}^{x} \sqrt[t^2]{\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt = 2\sqrt[x^2]{\cos(x)}$. But I am not sure if it is right and what to do next.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{-x}^{x} \sqrt[t^2]{\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt \not= 2\sqrt[x^2]{\cos(x)}$. You need to first find the integral before plugging in the limits (which is also incorrect).

Comment: Hi, could you give me a tip why it is incorrect? I used fundamental theorem of calculus but I guess I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is defined over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\setminus\{0\}$. However the function has a removable singularity at $0$, because
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x)^{1/x^2}=e^{-1/2}
$$
which can be proved by considering
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(1-\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
If we extend the function, we get a continuous function, let's call it $f$, and we have
$$
\int_{-x}^x (\cos t)^{1/t^2}\,dt=\int_{-x}^x f(t)\,dt
$$

Now you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{-x}^x f(t)\,dt
$$
with $f$ continuous in a neighborhood of $0$. Now apply the fundamental theorem of calculus with the advantage that, in this case,
$$
\int_{-x}^x f(t)\,dt=2\int_0^x f(t)\,dt
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I almost got it. But I am still confused with what happens with 1/x before we applied FTC.

Comment: @daLime If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, for instance $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$, then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)}{x}$ is the derivative at $0$ of $F$. What does the FTC say, now?

Comment: +1 this is where one should appreciate the meaning of FTC.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I think I am getting it.

$\underset{x\to 0}\lim\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to0}2(\cos x)^{1/x^2}$  


is it correct?

Comment: @daLime No. $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=f(0)$ (no limit after the first =)

Answer (score 0):

The fast way is to note that $f(x)=(\cos x)^{1/x^2}$ has a removable singularity at $x=0$ because the limit there is $e^{-1/2}$ so we can use the Lebesgue Density theorem to write

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2x}\int\limits_{-x}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt=e^{-1/2}$ so your limit is $2e^{-1/2}.$

From scratch, set $F(x)=\int\limits_{-x}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt=\int\limits_{-x}^0\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt+\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt=\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt-\int\limits_{0}^{-x}\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt.$

Now, note that

$\underset{x\to 0}\lim\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=F'(0)$ is exactly the limit you want. Now apply the FTC to $F:$

$F'(0)=e^{-1/2}+e^{-1/2}=2e^{-1/2}$ where we have used the chain rule on the second term.

Comment: Hi, did I get it right that we removed 1/x using definition of derivative?

Answer (score -2):

Using L'Hospital we get

> $$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac1x\int\limits_{-x}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt =
> \lim_{x\to0+}\frac2x\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt = 
> \lim_{x\to0+}2\sqrt[x^2]{\cos x}\,\mathrm  = 2e^{-\frac12} $$
>   because
>   $$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{ln(cosx)}{x^2} = 
> \lim_{x\to0+}\frac{-sinx}{2xcosx} = -\frac12 $$

Comment: Why the downvotes? I would be happy to get a hint what I did wrong.

Comment: I am not sure but it seem you lost 1/x

Comment: I assume you refer to the step
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac2x\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt = \lim_{x\to0+}2\sqrt[x^2]{\cos x}\,\mathrm dt$$
but I think it is correct - I used L'Hospital and FTC for this step
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac2x\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt 
= \lim_{x\to0+}\frac{2\int\limits_{0}^x\sqrt[t^2]{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt}{x} = \lim_{x\to0+}2\sqrt[x^2]{\cos x}\,\mathrm dt$$